# "Exception occured." message with IEC and COM

Tags: python, com

I try to drive web pages with IEC.

I am using multiprocessing also.

I keep get this error:

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024726), None)
[('test_IEC.py', 76, 'IECDrive', 'ie.Navigate(url)'), ('IEC.py', 86, 'Navigate', 'self.ie.Navigate(url)'), ('<COMObject InternetExplorer.Application>', 2, 'Navigate', None)]
```

How can I debug this error, or can you give me why this error occurs ?

Comment: Do you have any code to show ?

Comment: Nothing much...

'code'
for url in url_list:
    ie.Navigate(url)
    ie.PollWhileBusy()

I have url_list and it is separated to 4 processes with multiprocessing.

Comment: That will be hard to understand without anything. Where does this error occurs ? How did you retrieve it ?

Comment: it occurs at ie. Navigate(url)